# Shell, Unix, grep -v

Tags: shell, unix, grep

I know we can do `grep -v` in shell.
And I know we can do `grep -A2`.

Can we do `grep -v -A2`?

I want to remove 2 consecutive line. Just like `grep -A2`.

How do I do grep -v (2 lines)?

**Input file**

```
Eat rice

14677

Go school

1245677
```

**Output file**

```
Go school

1245677
```

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: Did you try it? What happened?

Comment: I tried grep -v -A2 -> WRONG SYNTAX. If I do grep -A2 (without -v) it works well

Comment: Try changing flag position. Instead of -v -A2 try with -A2 -v

Answer (score 2):

Easy to do with `sed`:

```sh
$ cat input.txt
Eat rice
14677
Go school
1245677
$ sed '/Eat rice/,+1d' input.txt
Go school
1245677
```

Deletes all lines matching `Eat rice` and the one following, prints the rest.